# ArrayAdapter behaves wierdly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using custom adapter whose getView() method is not being called.I have a callback interface method which is called when async task is finished doing it's work.

```
    public class Student extends Activity implements AsyncFinishInterface
    {

        private ListView list;

            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.student_screen);

            list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewList);
             new Aynctask().execute();

        }
@Override
    public void finish(String response, String method) throws Exception {

        ArrayList<Friend> FriendList= new ArrayList<Friend>();
        Friend friend;
        JSONObject row;
        JSONObject json= new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("Friends");
        int size=jsonArray.length();
        Friend[] friendArray= new Friend[size];
        for(int i=0 ; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
        {           
            friend = new Friend();
            row= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            friend.setFirstName(row.getString("firstName"));
            friend.setLastName(row.getString("lastName"));
            friend.setEmail(row.getString("email"));

            friendArray[i]=friend;
                        }
ContentAdapter contentAdapter= new ContentAdapter(this, R.layout.friend_detail, friendArray);
        list.setAdapter(contentAdapter);      //Till here it's working fine.
    }



class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {
        Context context;
        int layoutResourceId;
        Friend data[] = null;

        public ContentAdapter(Context context, int resource, Friend[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            this.layoutResourceId = resource;
            this.data = objects;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            //          ContentsHolder holder;
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Home_Screen) context)
                    .getLayoutInflater();
            return row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }


    }
```

Does any one have Idea what's going wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewFrndImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/app_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFrndName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textViewFrndEmail"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageViewFrndImage"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewFrndEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewFrndName"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewFrndImage"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: int i= super.getCount();
            return i; you should return data.length

Comment: debug your code and check size of `objects` on constructor of Adapter, you don't need `getCount` in `ArrayAdapter`, remove that

Comment: about getcount() it's not even being called

Comment: @shayan I have debugged it and yes I am getting values in the constructor.

Comment: so remove getCount method and see the result

Comment: @shayan getcount() was just to see if that is getting called. I don't need it. I have already tried that but still not working

Comment: did you get any error?

Comment: can you please post your friend_detail code ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be instead of:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = ((Home_Screen) context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
```

Try this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater =LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

See if it works !

Comment: `getCount` not be needed on `ArrayAdapter` class, this need on `BaseAdapter`

Comment: Edited, I got confused. Thanks !